# Is there a $D$- chain between two point of a connected component in an uniform space?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

A uniform space $(X, U)$ is said to be uniformly connected if every uniformly continuous map
of the space into a discrete space is a constant map also a topological space is connected if and
only if the only mapping of the space into a discrete space is a constant mapping. This implies
that if uniform space $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is connected, then for each pair $x,y\in X$ and each $U\in\mathcal{U}$, there is
an integer $n$ such that $(x, y)\in U^n$.

Let $A\subseteq X$ is a connected component ($X$ is not necessary connected). Let $x,y\in A$ and $D\in\mathcal{U}$ be given. Is there an integer $n$ such that $(x, y)\in U^n$?

Please help me to know it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you mean uniform-connected component.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma,Thanks. In a paper, author claimed that uniformity generated by the subsets $D_n$( $n\in\mathbb{N}$) of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, where $(x,y)\in D_n$  if and only if $x\equiv y$ mod $2^n$, has at least one non-trivial
connected component, but this is not clear for me. Please  help me to know  it.